# drupal_add_html_head just after drupal_add_js

Tags: drupal

I want add the cookiebot script external

```
<script id="Cookiebot" src="https://consent.cookiebot.com/uc.js" data-cbid="idcookiebot" data-culture="languageId" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Just after this

```
drupal_add_js("window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() { window.dataLayer.push(arguments); }
    gtag('consent', 'default', {
    ad_storage: 'denied',
    analytics_storage: 'denied',
    wait_for_update: 500,
    });",
    array('type' => 'inline')
  );
```

But, with drupal_add_html_head, the external script is located in the first line, but a I need this after the script.

I can't find how drupal_add_js add external JS with data elements

Answer (score 0):

You can set `scope` and `weight` for extra javascript like this:

```php
drupal_add_js("window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() { window.dataLayer.push(arguments); }
    gtag('consent', 'default', {
    ad_storage: 'denied',
    analytics_storage: 'denied',
    wait_for_update: 500,
    });",
    array(
        'type' => 'inline',
        'scope' => 'footer',
        'weight' => 5,
    )
);
```